# Disable ARC on specific lines of code

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang, automatic-ref-counting, llvm

I am turning a project into ARC, but there are some bits of code that can only work with ARC disabled.  I realize that **-fno-objc-arc** can be used for disabling ARC on a per file basis.  However I was wondering if it was possible to disable ARC on a per function basis.

I know that warnings can be toggled on a per line basis for example

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Weverything"
// Code goes here
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Is there something similar for ARC?  (Below is my hypothetical idea)

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic flag "-fno-objc-arc"
// Code goes here
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: "can only work with ARC disabled" sounds a bit suspicious.  If true, that would suggest that there are programs that can't be written in an ARC environment.

Comment: True.  Some things can not be written in ARC.  For example , structs with objective c objects.  This is disallowed in ARC and porting a struct to a class is not an option.

Comment: Doing it line-by-line would disable some of ARC's ability to do its RR optimizing -- basically make ARC itself pointless for the scope containing that line, as far as I can see. Disabling it on a scope basis -- per function/method, for example -- seems like it would be possible, but probably is not useful enough to justify the maintenance.

Comment: @Calimari328 You can't use obj-c references in structs in Obj-C, but you can in Objective-C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible. You'll have to move your non-ARC code to a separate file. If this is code in an Obj-C class, perhaps you could move the methods in question to a category.

EDIT:

Using Objective-C++ can get around some of the restrictions of ARC in Obj-C. For example, you can put Obj-C references in structs. (Because they can have deinitializers in C++)

EDIT:

This code works for me:

**test.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

struct Struct {
    id ref ;
    NSDate * date ;
};
```

**main.mm**

```
#import "test.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        Struct a ;
        a.ref = [ NSObject new ] ;

        Struct * a2 = new Struct() ;
        a2->ref = [ NSObject new ] ;
        free( a2 ) ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?  I tried putting  struct Example { NSDate*d; } in the .h file then turned its .m into a .mm  but it still says it can't do it.  Am I missing something?